Looking for information on this Apollo era CGI animation
In the NASA documentary The Computer and Manned Space Flight, early CGI animations of lunar landing, rendezvous, earthrise etc. are shown. The narration says that these simulations were made prior to the first manned lunar landing.
I'm seeking more information about these early CGI simulations:

What specific systems were used to create these simulations?

Are there any papers or technical reports detailing the development and use of these simulations?

Are there any archives or repositories where more examples of these simulations can be viewed?


Any additional context or resources about these CGI would be appreciated.

(Apollo Experience Report: Simulation of Manned Space Flight for Crew Training) The Gemini part task trainer (repurposed for Apollo) used an electronic image generator, drawn on the face of a CRT. The image generation contained nine degrees
of freedom and produced such phenomena as line of sight blanking, illumination, shadowing, and perspective distortion. Simple target shapes (cylinders, cones, and
others) as well as combinations of these shapes were readily simulated with simple
surface markings and details. (Vector drawn game Spacewar! was written in 1962)

It is quite possible that these animations were generated by the simulation, and then recorded to film (as you could do then, frame by frame), for playback as presentations (ie. the LM animation), or for periods where there is not much input required (Earthrise, etc). I did read something about the latter being the case, therefore simplistic visuals were thought sufficient.

@blobbymcblobby I've always wanted to know more about those part-task trainers. The Apollo Mission Simulator didn't have any graphical displays like that at all, just some really ingenious out-the-window stuff. I wonder what the nine degrees of freedom were.

different, but related: Apollo training simulator cgi requirements

IIRC there was a split prism used for the out of window view as well, it allowed for the CRT image to combine with a view of Earth (if required) that was pre-filmed footage of a model; so you ended up looking out of the window at a vector drawn image next to a 'photoreal' Earth in space. (it might also have been an optical television view (of the model Earth), but only when 'close' enough)

This seems like more of a VFX question than a space exploration one.

Whoever thinks this belongs on the meta site...
